# Returning a cell reference when it meets a condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have spreadsheet with student names, ages and test scores.
I want to loop through the 4th column (student ages) which has already been sorted from lowest to highest.
The loop notes the age of the first and youngest student in cell "D1" but I want it to stop looping when it hits on a cell where the student's age is 4 years older than the student in "D1" e.g:
11 (Cell "D1")
11
11
12
12
13
14
15 (As this student is 4 years older than cell "D1", I want it to return "D6".

I would then like to repeat the process with "D6" (or whatever the cell reference will be) now being the initial starting point and returning the cell when it hits on a cell when the student is 4 years older.

Here is what I have done already. I'm really new to this, so let me apologise in advance! Any help would be appreciated as I'm really stuck.

```
    function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var firstAge = activeSheet.getRange("D1").getValue()
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();

  for(var i=1;i<lastrow+1;i++){
      var column4 = activeSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();

          if (column4 === firstAge + 4) {
            activeSheet.getRange().getRowIndex(column4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my4Loop() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var oA=[];
  var age1=vA[0][3];
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
      if(vA[i][3]-age1>=4)
      {
        var a1=sh.getRange(i+1,4);
        oA.push(a1.getA1Notation());
        age1=vA[i][3];
        a1.setBackground('#ffff00');//Mark the wiener
      }
  }
  Logger.log(oA);
return oA;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. If you don't mind, me asking, what does the '.push' function do exactly?

Comment: The push method is an array method which adds elements to an array.  In this case I'm just saving the locations which achieve the conditiion.[This is an excellent online resource for Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
function getCells(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(YOUR_SHEET_NAME);
var targetColumn = "D";
var values = sheet.getRange(targetColumn + "1:" + targetColumn + sheet.getLastRow())
                  .getValues();

var cursorAt = values[0];
var result = [];

values.forEach(function(item, index){

    if (item[0] - cursorAt == 4) {

      cursorAt = item[0];
      result.push("D" + (index + 1));
    }

  });  


return result;  


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I have some questions if you don’t mind answering them. Am I correct in thinking:

var cursorAt = values[0];
//values[0], does this set the value at 0 or does it set the position from the first cell?     

values.forEach(function(item, index){
//does this function record the content of the cell- ‘item’ and its position in column “d”-index?     

if (item[0] - cursorAt == 4) {
//This looks as though it relates to the line above (item, index). Does item[0] refer to the age?     

cursorAt = item[0];
result.push("D" + (index + 1));
//I’m not sure if I understand these two lines.

Comment: Answering your questions will, unfortunately, require a crash course in JavaScript, which goes far beyond the scope of the question asked. Codeacademy has a free JS starter course recommended by Google. I'm afraid none of the solutions offered here will be of any use to you if don't get yourself familiar with these basic concepts.

Comment: Here's how the result of calling getValues() on a 'range' looks like https://prntscr.com/gf5u6w It's a 2D array (array of arrays) where each inner array represents a row of data. You then call the forEach() method on the array to iterate over the values (forEach() is a part of Array.prototype, which means you can all it on any array). Here, 'item' represents one of the inner arrays. We get age value by selecting the first element from the inner array (item[0]).

Comment: By default, we will do the comparison against the first value of the array (we set 'cursorAt' equal to it).  If we find the element that's greater than 'cursorAt' exactly by 4, we 1) set 'cursorAt' equal to that new value 2) append the string coordinates of the cell to the results array. Adding together strings and numbers will concatenate them, so 'D' + (0 + 1) will return 'D1'. We need to add 1 to the index of the element in the array because arrays are zero-indexed (start with 0) whereas the rows in the spreadsheet start with 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this will help you:


     function myFunction() {
      var app = SpreadsheetApp;
      var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
      var firstAge =activeSheet.getRange("D1:D"+lastRow).getCell(1,1).getValue();
var allval=column4=activeSheet.getRange("D1:D"+lastRow).getvalues();
      for(var i=0;i<allval.length;i++){

              if (allval[i][0] == firstAge + 4) {
                Logger.log('Row Index:'+(i+1));
                break;}
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate it.